# Binding Image to ListView in VB.net (Windows Store)

Tags: vb.net, listview, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a problem with binding images to ListView in VB.net. I'm building an app that will resize, convert and compress images, but I would like the selected images to be displayed in a ListView, alongside the image name.

This is the XAML code for the ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="481" Margin="10,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1069" BorderBrush="#FF003859" Foreground="White" Background="#42FFFFFF" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="6,0,6,6" FontSize="16" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="vertical">
                        <Grid Height="160" Margin="6">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Width="160" Height="160">
                                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImageID}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                            </Border>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here is the code for Image class:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class Image</code>

    Private _Title As String
    Private _ImageID As BitmapImage

    Public ReadOnly Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return _Title
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Image() As BitmapImage
        Get
            Return _ImageID
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal Title As String, ByVal ImageID As BitmapImage)
        _Title = Title
        _ImageID = ImageID
    End Sub

End Class
```

And here is the code for the button that adds the images in the ListView:

```
Private Async Sub AddImage_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles AddImage.Click

        Dim picker As New FileOpenPicker()

        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tiff")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tga")

        Dim files As IReadOnlyList(Of StorageFile) = Await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync

        Dim imagearray(10000000) As BitmapImage
        Dim i = 0
        If files.Count > 0 Then
            For Each file In files
                imagearray(i) = New BitmapImage(New Uri(file.Path))
                i += 1
            Next
            Dim j = 0
            For Each file In files
                ListView.Items.Add(New Image(file.Name, imagearray(j)))
                j += 1
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
```

Please help me out with this.

Edit:

ListView XAML Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="481" Margin="10,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1069" BorderBrush="#FF003859" Foreground="White" Background="#42FFFFFF" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="6,0,6,6" FontSize="16" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="vertical">
                        <Grid Height="160" Margin="6">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Width="160" Height="160">
                                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImageID}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                            </Border>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Image Class:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class Image

    Private _Title As String
    Private _Image As BitmapImage

    Public ReadOnly Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return _Title
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property ImageID() As BitmapImage
        Get
            Return _Image
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal Title As String, ByVal ImageID As BitmapImage)
        _Title = Title
        _Image = ImageID
    End Sub

End Class
```

The button:

```
Dim ImageCollection As New Collection(Of Image)

     Private Async Sub AddImage_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles AddImage.Click

            Dim picker As New FileOpenPicker()

            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop
            picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg")
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg")
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp")
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif")
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png")
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tiff")
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tga")

            Dim files As IReadOnlyList(Of StorageFile) = Await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync

            Dim imagearray(10000000) As BitmapImage
            Dim i = 0
            If files.Count > 0 Then
                For Each file In files
                    imagearray(i) = New BitmapImage(New Uri(file.Path))
                    i += 1
                Next
                Dim j = 0
                For Each file In files
                    ImageCollection.Add(New Image(file.Name, imagearray(j)))
                    j += 1
                Next
                For Each file In files
                    ListView.ItemsSource = ImageCollection
                Next

            End If

        End Sub
```

This is the code I have now, but the images are still not shown. What is wrong?

**Here is the new edit:**

**ListView XAML Code:**

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" DataContext="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="481" Margin="10,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1069" BorderBrush="#FF003859" Foreground="White" Background="#42FFFFFF" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderThickness="6,0,6,6" FontSize="16" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="vertical">
                        <Grid Height="160" Margin="6">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Width="160" Height="160">
                                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImageProperty}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                            </Border>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleProperty}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**Image Class:**

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class Image

    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private ImageX As BitmapImage
    Private TitleX As String

    Public ReadOnly Property ImageProperty() As BitmapImage
        Get
            Return ImageX
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property TitleProperty() As String
        Get
            Return TitleX
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal ImageTitle As String, ByVal ImageID As BitmapImage)
        TitleX = ImageTitle
        ImageX = ImageID
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

End Class
```

**And the Button with ImageCollection Class:**

```
 Dim ImageCollection As New ImageCollectionClass

    Private Async Sub AddImage_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles AddImage.Click

        Dim picker As New FileOpenPicker()

        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tiff")
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tga")

        Dim files As IReadOnlyList(Of StorageFile) = Await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync

        Dim imagearray(10000000) As BitmapImage
        Dim i = 0
        If files.Count > 0 Then
            For Each file In files
                imagearray(i) = New BitmapImage(New Uri(file.Path))
                i += 1
            Next
            Dim j = 0
            For Each file In files
                ImageCollection.AddImage(file.Name, imagearray(j))
                j += 1
            Next
            For Each file In files
                ListView.ItemsSource = ImageCollection
            Next

        End If

    End Sub

Public Class ImageCollectionClass

    Public ImageCollectionClass As New ObservableCollection(Of Image)

    Public Sub AddImage(ByVal ImageTitleInClass As String, ByVal ImageIDInClass As BitmapImage)
        ImageCollectionClass.Add(New Image(ImageTitleInClass, ImageIDInClass))
    End Sub

End Class
```

**But it doesn't work. Tell me please what's wrong now!**

Comment: what part are you having difficultly with?  I don't see a collection here that would be the DataContext of your ListView, additionally you'll want to make sure that Image and your collection support the INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: How can I create a collection? What would you add here for it to work? Please help, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: upon looking a little further I can see you're pushing data into the ListView directly... instead of ListView.Items.Add, create a collection of the Image class, then use set your DataContest to that list. You don't want to tie your UI so tightly to your data.  Check out the Split Template project that you can generate from Visual Studio, it should give you an idea of how to better set up your application.

Comment: I made an edit, can you look at it please and see what is wrong?

Comment: ListView.ItemsSource = ImageCollection need be done only once, no need to be in a for loop, but the bigger issue is that your Image class doesn't implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), which is part of the binding 'plumbing' you also want ImageCollection to be an ObservableCollection for the same reason.  That should get you closer

Comment: @JimO'Neil I updated my code. Please advice me now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original loop is rather convoluted (thought that's not the immediate cause of the program).  All of this code:

```
    Dim imagearray(10000000) As BitmapImage
    Dim i = 0
    If files.Count > 0 Then
        For Each file In files
            imagearray(i) = New BitmapImage(New Uri(file.Path))
            i += 1
        Next
        Dim j = 0
        For Each file In files
            ImageCollection.AddImage(file.Name, imagearray(j))
            j += 1
        Next
        For Each file In files
            ListView.ItemsSource = ImageCollection
        Next
    End If
```

could be collapsed to:

```
    For Each file In files
        ImageCollection.AddImage(file.Name, New BitmapImage(New Uri(file.Path)))
    Next
    ListView.ItemsSource = ImageCollection.ImageCollectionClass
```

Note you need `ImageCollectionClass` as your `ItemsSource`.

From there, you can incorporate code from Scenario 2 of the [XAML Images Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9) and modify to get the image via [SetSourceAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync.aspx):

```
    Dim fileStream As IRandomAccessStream
    For Each file In files
        fileStream = Await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)

        Dim bitmapImage As New BitmapImage()
        Await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream)

        ImageCollection.AddImage(file.Name, bitmapImage)
    Next
    ListView.ItemsSource = ImageCollection.ImageCollectionClass
```

Comment: I have just one more issue. When I navigate to the next page of my program with Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(NextPage)) and go back to the main page with Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(MainPage)), the ListView is cleared and I have to add the items again.

Comment: that's likely because you're reinitializing ImageCollection when the page is recreated, which it will be when you navigate back to it.  You can make ImageCollection persist between page navigation or you could consider using [NavigationCacheMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode.aspx)